# using https on a flask local development?

Tags: python, ssl, flask

i am so much curious to understand how ssl works so i have decided to use ssl on my local flask development environment. i have read this article [flask.pocoo.org...ts](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/) but i can not understand where i will get the `yourserver.key` and `yourserver.crt` files?

please give me some idea about having those files for free! i have seen many company sell ssl but i want a free one for my local development just in my computer only.

I am on windows 7

Answer (score 5):

[openssl](https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html) bundles utilities to create all required keys and certificates, and since you're only going to use it locally, you can self-sign the certificate using the same utility. You can either use the openssl version available in your distro or from OpenSSL, or if on Windows, a pre-compiled version from OpenSSL.

From [The Most Common OpenSSL Commands](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html):

Generate a new private key and Certificate Signing Request

```
openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
```

Generate a self-signed certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
```

Generate a certificate signing request (CSR) for an existing private key

```
openssl req -out CSR.csr -key privateKey.key -new
```

Generate a certificate signing request based on an existing certificate

```
openssl x509 -x509toreq -in certificate.crt -out CSR.csr -signkey privateKey.key
```

Remove a passphrase from a private key

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.pem -out newPrivateKey.pem
```

Comment: Is it just me or did this not fully explain how to generate the .crt and .key files needed by the OP? Which combination of these commands are needed?